# Conda and Linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, centos7

My OS is CentOs7.

I recently installed Conda and Mamba.  Everything was working, but now it looks like that isn't the case. I cannot call Mamba. I can barely make Conda do anything. Initially, I installed Bakta, which works, but nothing else is and I continue to get messages about package incompatabilities. I thought maybe the environment I was in was potentially too updated for the new program, so I researched it and boom yes the program wants a few older versions (Python 3.6.5 for example) so I tried to download it and I got a lot of flack (aka everything is incompatable).  This could make sense as I upgraded conda or updated --all, but I then tried to create a new environment and now conda won't even create an environment and it fails to resolve any issues.  I tried going through PIP3 and it looks like numpy is not able to create a wheel, so I tried addressing that and it keeps just crashing out. Am I at this point to believe conda is broken? Here is the first error I am getting:

> > ```
> >  INFO:
> > ```

```
  ########### CLIB COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
  INFO: Platform      :
    Architecture: x64
    Compiler    : unix-like
  
  CPU baseline  :
    Requested   : 'min'
    Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
    Flags       : -msse -msse2 -msse3
    Extra checks: none
  
  CPU dispatch  :
    Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
    Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2
    Generated   : none
  INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> /tmp/pip-install-skejmo98/numpy_05946e1a2d574651a6019d72e428adca/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: If I can give you an advice: choose one package manager and stick to it. A package manager will not be aware of any change made by another package manager. You messed up your python environment, you can either spend hour trying to undo what you've done or install a new clean environment.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up doing just that and have reduced my package managers to one.  So your advice was very good!  Thank you!